# Issue With Salesforce CLI update

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, cli

Hi I have just updated the version of the Salesforce CLI--from 7.110.0 ----- to 7.129.0-c662c12

After Update i am getting below error :---

```
19:19:27.198 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias test --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
19:19:27.359 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias test --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
 ended with exit code 3221225785
```

Note : - I am not able to degrade the version of the Salesforce CLI and not able to install the another version as well.

Comment: Does your browser window open to test.salesforce.com to prompt you to log in?

Comment: Yes my Browser Window Opens

Comment: So you sign in, but it fails to connect and then you receive the exit code?

Comment: Yes its wired very very Wired